# Formulário de Contato não Funciona PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou com um **problema** no formulário de contato do meu site, acredito que ele esteja configurado corretamente porém ele não está enviando o email pelo formulário, gostaria de saber se é erro no código, é a única coisa que está faltando para terminar.

O código `PHP` está assim:

```
  <?php

  $name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
  $from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
  $subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
  $message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
  $to           = "comercial@slimart.com.br";//replace with your email

  $headers   = array();
  $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
  $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
  $headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
  $headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
  $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
  $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

  die;

  ?>
```

E o `html` assim:

```
  <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Nome">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Sua Mensagem"></textarea>
  </div>                        
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Enviar">
   </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Esse código PHP está dentro do ficheiro `sendemail.php`? e já agora o nome é mesmo esse ou é `sendmail.php` (sem `e`)? Outra coisa, não vejo o campo `subject`...

Comment: isso `sendemail.php` é esse nos dois

Comment: @Sergio você sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: No seu HTML não tem o campo "subject" e sem esta informação a função mail do PHP não funciona!

Comment: e como poderia fazer pra funcionar @igormello ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para executar a função mail do PHP as informações mínimas para seu funcionamento são **$to** (para quem enviar), **$subject** (assunto do email) e **$message** (a mensagem).
No seu exemplo no HTML não tem o input de subject e no script php na linha 5 **($_POST['subject'])** você busca por ele, proposta de solução adicionar mais um input no seu html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto do emial"></input>
</div>
```

Outra alternativa seria adicionar um assunto default direto no php:

```
$subject = "Assunto default do email";
```

Adicional:

Olhando melhor seu código vi que nos headers você usa um `Array`, só que na função mail os headers são uma `String` então você tem que usar a função `implode` pra trasformar em String.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Olhei também que você usa o `$from` este email que é usado ai tem que ser um email válido e criado no seu servidor que esta hospedado este script.

```
$from = "email@meuservidorqueestahospedado.com";
```

Comment: @Victor Gomes foi útil a resposta?

Comment: Amigo, mesmo assim continua sem funcionar

Comment: Tentei as duas formas, colocando o novo input e tentando pelo default

Comment: você tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: @VictorGomes gera algum erro?

Comment: Não, não gera, aparentemente tudo bem porém o email não chega e eu já tentei enviar um email normal para o endereço em que esta no formulário e chega, o problema é quando envia a mensagem pelo formulário, ai não funciona

Comment: @VictorGomes melhorei um pouco a resposta dá uma olhada!

Comment: Problema resolvido, obrigado Igor

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está fazendo um array do header, o que deveria ser uma string, veja se fazendo como abaixo o problema resolve:

```
  $name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
  $from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
  $subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
  $message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
  $to         = "comercial@slimart.com.br";//replace with your email

  $headers   = array();
  $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
  $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
  $headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
  $headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
  $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
  $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
  /* 
     A função "implode" irá concatenar os
     valores do array e converter em uma
     string com a intersecção: "\r\n" 
  */
 $header = implode("\r\n", $headers);
 if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)) {
    echo "enviado";
 }
```