# Não estou recebendo os dados enviados pelo usuario no email que deveria receber. Alguma dica como resolver?

Tags: php

Preciso de ajuda. Tenho um formulario de contacto a funcionar mas o nome, email e mensagem de quem envia nao chega ao email de quem recebe. Onde esta o erro no php? Desde ja o meu muito obrigado.

PHP

```
<?
$nome=$_POST['nome'];

$email=$_POST['email'];

$titulo=$_POST['titulo'];

$texto=$_POST['texto'];


$Destinatario="email a receber";


$Titulo="$titulo";


$mensagem1="

Uma mensagem vinda do site !

Algum vistante mandou essa mensagem pelo site.

Nome: $nome

Email: $email

Mensagem: $texto";


mail("$Destinatario","$Titulo", "$mensagem1","From:$email");

?>
```

Código html

```
<form method="post" action="contacto.php">
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Nome"  required="">
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Email " required="" >
      <textarea  placeholder="Mensagem" requried=""></textarea>         

      <label class="hvr-sweep-to-right">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
      </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Melhore sua questão e coloque seu código tanto html quanto PHP.

Comment: Talvez te ajude.---> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122488/formul%C3%A1rio-de-contato-n%C3%A3o-funciona-php/122578

Comment: troca o `<?` por  <?php` e o mail() faça assim, `if(!mail("$Destinatario","$Titulo", "$mensagem1","From:$email")){ echo 'erro '. error_get_last();}`

Comment: Obrigado Igor mas nao ajudou. O código que está no post que recomendou também já tentei, entre outros e nenhum dá. Todos dizem email enviado ao usuario mas a verdade é que não recebo nada no meu mail. Ok ja vi a sua sugestão. Vou tentar

Comment: rray, infelizmente não deu

Comment: Já olhou na caixa de *span*?

Comment: Sim Igor, já vi e nada.

Comment: É isto que aparece no mail:
 Uma mensagem vinda do site !                                                                Algum vistante mandou essa mensagem pelo site.

Nome: 

Email: 

Mensagem:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca o código abaixo no lugar do `From:$email`

```
$headers = 'From: '$email . '\r\n' .
    'Reply-To: '. $email . '\r\n' .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

deixando o código assim

```
mail($Destinatario, $Titulo, $mensagem1, $headers);
```

e faltam também os atributos "name" no formulário

Comment: Realmente faltam os `name=""` nas `tags`!

Comment: Daniel, o nome e email do usuario ja aparece mas a mensagem ainda nao

Comment: Caros Amigos, problemas resolvidos. Muito obrigado!!!!